# live math reactjs using data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

i try to make a live math of product price multiplied by product quantity while the product quantity increased or decreased using +- button i made and product price retrieved from API. i have no problem gathering it, but i can't do a math with these. please help me

+- button code

```
IncrementItem(){
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  }
  DecreaseItem(){
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks - 1 });
  }
  ToggleClick(){
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  }
```

product price code

```
{products.harga}
```

and i intent to put the total here:

```
var price = <div className="totalhrg"><NumberFormat value={products.harga} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'Rp. '} /></div>;
```

again, thanks in advance! you guys really a good, skilled, and very helpful person!

Comment: Is the increment and decrement of the state not working

Comment: Could you: `console.log(typeof products.harga)`. The reason I want to know this, is because you can only multiply numbers with numbers. Therefore you probably need to parse it to a number.

Comment: its working, the thing is i dont know to make a live math using the value of the decrement and increment as quantity and product.price

Comment: @Jurrian i use {products.harga} in render() block, then how to console log in render?

Comment: Just run it before you return something from render().

Comment: its said number

Answer (score 0):

first of all   you shouldn't set state like this:

```
this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 }); // WRONG
```

use this instead:

```
 this.setState((prevState) => ({ clicks: prevState.clicks + 1 })) // CORRECT
```

This is because the this.state.clicks does not get updated until the component has been re-rendered and this make problems.

for your case best practice is storing card info into an array like this one:

```
card = [
{
 id : 1,
 price: 4000,
 quantity: 2
},
{
 id : 2,
 price: 8000,
 quantity: 1
}
]
```

Now you have to change your methods:

```
  IncrementItem(id){
        this.setState((prevState) => (
          {
            ...prevState ,
            card: prevState.card.map(carItem => 
              carItem.id === id  
              ? {...carItem, quantity: cardItem.quantity + 1}
              : {...carItem}
            )
         }));
  }
  DecreaseItem(id){
        this.setState((prevState) => (
          {
            ...prevState ,
            card: prevState.card.map(carItem => 
              carItem.id === id  
              ? {...carItem, quantity: cardItem.quantity - 1}
              : {...carItem}
            )
         }));
  }
```

and then you can easily calculate card sum

```
  cardSum(){
    const sum = 0
    for (i = 0, i < this.state.card.length; i++) {
      sum += this.state.card[i].quantity * this.state.card[i].price
    }
    return sum
  }
```

and also can use this in JSX

```
{this.state.card.map(cardItem , () => (
  <div className="totalhrg">
    <NumberFormat
      value={cardItem.quantity * cardItem.price } 
      key={cardItem.id}
      displayType={'text'}
      thousandSeparator={true}
      prefix={'Rp. '} />
  </div>
))};
```

Comment: the code you shows contain an array with multiple data while in my case i only return array with 1 data. i think the code will be different right? since i couldn't use .map because it is not an array

Comment: @NaufalSyauqi you can use array even if there is only one item. if you must avoid using array , you can just use this line ```value={this.item.quantity * this.item.price }``` which this.item is your data object !